# Installing python packages for Spyder on mcOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, spyder

I just installed Spyder to work with python on my mcOS using the [standalone installer](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html#standalone-installers).

Now, I have Spyder running with the python located in:`/Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/MacOS/python`.

I want to install python packages. However, the default pip3 is associated to the default python of my mac, located in: `/opt/local/bin/python`.

As a result, packages installed via `pip3 install package` in the terminal can not be loaded from Spyder Ipython.

I changed the Spyder python interpreter from default to, but it says that `spyder-kernels` are not installed. However, `pip3 install spyder-kernels` return `ERROR: No matching distribution found for test`.

How do I make a clean installation of spyder on Mac (without Anaconda), and install correpsonding python packages for it ?

Comment: I suggest to go with the option based on `virtualenv` - you have it listed on `Spyder`'s page. This way, you will be able to completely isolate `Spyder`'s env from the default one.

Comment: I'm actually setting up Spyder on this computer so new user of python can start with easily, rather than doing everything from terminal from example. I don't think using a virtual env. is going to help for that.

Comment: Also I should be able to use the stadalone installer and install python packages ...